# Change one value in list value in Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

```
Information = [
    {'Man1' : ['Martin', False]},
    {'Man2' : ['Joseph', True]}
]

Information['Man2'][1]= True
print(Information['Man2'][1])
```

How can I change 1 value inside of list as value in Dictionary?

Comment: Why do you need a list of dictionaries for this? It could just be `info = {'Martin': False, 'Joseph': True}`. Or better yet, simply keep a list or set of names that are `True`, and assume a name is `False` if not found.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 Would cause a problem if two person have the same name.

Comment: @Vollfeiw - True. However, I suspect they would be unique as otherwise their associated value would be ambiguous. "Man1," "Man2" etc. seem like a stand-in for an unneeded list rather than providing information. There just really isn't enough information to provide a guaranteed improvement on this code, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the array to get to the result you wanted :

```
Information = {
    'Man1' : ['Martin', False],
    'Man2' : ['Joseph', True]
}

Information['Man2'][1]= True
print(Information['Man2'][1])
```

With that said, as it seems to be "Man(n)" as keys, you can do :

```
Information = [
    ['Martin', False],
    ['Joseph', True]
]

Information[1][1]= True
print(Information[1][1])
```

Or a list of dict :

```
Information = [
    {'name':'Martin', 'data':False},
    {'name':'Joseph', 'data':True}
]

Information[1]['data']= True
print(Information[1]['data'])
```

I put data here, because i don't know what your bool is for

Answer (score 0):

Its a list of dictionaries. So start with list index then dictionary key.

```
Information[1]['Man2'][1]= True
print(Information[1]['Man2'][1])
```

Comment: Thank you. I got confused with types of parentheses